# What does ”libel schmibel” mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, colloquial-language, reduplication

> Libel schmibel. The dead can't sue.

What does “libel schmibel” mean?

Another word to say it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shm-reduplication:

> **Shm-reduplication** is a form of reduplication in which the original word or its first syllable (the **base**) is repeated with the copy (the **reduplicant**) beginning with **shm-** (sometimes **schm-**), pronounced /ʃm/. The construction is generally used to indicate irony, sarcasm, derision, skepticism, or lack of interest with respect to comments about the discussed object:
>
> > He's just a baby!
> >     "Baby-shmaby". He's already 5 years old!
>
> The speaker is being skeptical. They do not think their kid is a baby or babyish.
>
> > What a sale!
> >     "Sale, schmale". I'm waiting for a larger discount.
>
> The speaker is showing lack of interest. They do not care about the sale.

Your example is analogous to the examples above.

Comment: You fail to mention that the most important point: This came into English from Yiddish.